# How do I perform set theory minus operation between two lists in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have the following case class

```
case class Cart(userId: Int, ProductId :Int, SellerId:Int, Qty: Int)
```

I have the following lists :

```
val mergedCart :List[Cart]=  List(Cart(900,1,1,2),Cart(900,2,2,2),Cart(901,3,3,2),Cart(901,2,2,2),Cart(901,1,1,2),Cart(900,4,2,1))

val userCart:List[Cart] = List(Cart(900,1,1,2),Cart(900,2,2,2),Cart(900,4,2,1))

val guestCart:List[Cart] = List(Cart(901,3,3,2),Cart(901,2,2,2),Cart(901,1,1,2))

val commonCart = List(Cart(900,2,2,4), Cart(900,1,1,4))
```

My requirement is that I have to get the following list as the output:

```
List(Cart(900,2,2,4),Cart(900,1,1,4),Cart(901,3,3,2),Cart(900,4,2,1))
```

The final list should have the common objects from `userCart` and `guestCart` based on the `ProductId`,`SellerId` combination and the quantity of both the objects get added. Then, the other objects present in `userCart` and `guestCart` which do not match the common objects should also be present in the final list in the output.

I am new to Scala and I am not able to solve this, kindly help me with this code.

Comment: When combining common elements, if the `userId` values don't match how is the resulting `userId` decided?

Comment: If the userId does not match, the requirement is to always display the userId of the userCart in the final list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't care about ordering in resulting list (so basically your result is a `Set`) , it's as simple as that:

```
def sum(a: Cart, b: Cart) = {
   //require(a.userId == b.userId)
   a.copy(Qty = a.Qty + b.Qty)
}

(userCart ++ guestCart)
  .groupBy(x => x.ProductId -> x.SellerId)
  .mapValues(_.reduce(sum _))
  .values
  .toList //toSet is more appropriate here
```

Results:

```
List(Cart(900,4,2,1), Cart(900,2,2,4), Cart(900,1,1,4), Cart(901,3,3,2))
```

**(!)** Be aware that I just took *first* `userId` in case of collision (see `sum` function). However, it preserves priority of users over guests if that's what implied.

Being represented as a `Set`, this result equals to your requirement:

```
scala> val mRes = List(Cart(900,4,2,1), Cart(900,2,2,4), Cart(900,1,1,4), Cart(901,3,3,2))
mRes: List[Cart] = List(Cart(900,4,2,1), Cart(900,2,2,4), Cart(900,1,1,4), Cart(901,3,3,2))

scala> val req = List(Cart(900,2,2,4),Cart(900,1,1,4),Cart(901,3,3,2),Cart(900,4,2,1))
req: List[Cart] = List(Cart(900,2,2,4), Cart(900,1,1,4), Cart(901,3,3,2), Cart(900,4,2,1))

scala> mRes.toSet == req.toSet
res17: Boolean = true
```

Explanations:

- `++` concatenates two lists
- `groupBy` groups values by some predicate (like `x.ProductId -> x.SellerId` which equivalent to a tuple `(x.ProductId, x.SellerId)` in your case). It preserves order inside group, but groups themselves aren't ordered - that's why order in resulting list is undefined. The operator returns `Map[Key, List[Value]]`, in your case `Map[(Int, Int), List[Cart]]`
- `mapValues` iterates over lists with carts
- `reduce` inside `mapValues` reduces List with carts by summing carts using `sum` function
- I didn't have to reattach objects with unique `(x.ProductId, x.SellerId)` as they were represented just as lists with one element, so `reduce` function didn't touch them - it just returned first (and only) element.
- `a.copy(Qty = ...)` makes copy of `a` with modified `Qty` field. In our case I take left element as a template, so elements that preced in the `(userCart ++ guestCart)` would have higher priority when `userId` is chosen.

---

Answering the headline's question about subtracting two sets:

```
scala> Set(1,2,3,4) - 4
res16: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)

scala> Set(1,2,3,4) -- Set(3,4)
res15: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2)
```

If elements of sets are instances of case classes (given that `hashCode`/`equals` methods weren't overridden) - it would compare all fields in order to check equality between two elements.

---

There is a theoretical connection of `groupBy` solution with a set theory. First, you can easily notice that my solution is representable with SQL's `GROUP BY` + `AGGREGATE` (`groupBy` with `reduce`-catamorphism in Scala). SQL is mostly based on relational-algebra, which in its turn partially based on set-theory, so here it is.

---

P.S. field/value/variable name in scala should always start with lowercase letter by convention. First capital letter means a constant.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me a lot!